# how to give custom test files path for detox e2e testing

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ios-ui-automation, detox

We are using Detox framework for IOS e2e testing. Detox by default created e2e folder and run all test files created under it.

Is there any way I can create the test files on some other folder and configure that path and run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set the path of the tests

As **Mocha** and **Jest** are only supported, therefore as mentioned in the [API](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md#mocha)

In your package.json

```
// For Mocha

"detox": {
      ...
      "test-runner": "mocha"
      "runner-config": "path/to/mocha.opts"
      "specs": "path/to/tests/root"
    }

// For Jest

"detox": {
      ...
      "test-runner": "jest"
      "runner-config": "path/to/config.json"
    }
```

where config.json is [this](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html)

Comment: thanks it worked for me. I have to put config.json and spec files in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Jest example:

```
"detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runner-config": "e2e/config.json" // default
    "configurations": {
      ...
    }
}
```

config.json example:

```
{
    ...
    "roots": ["../src/..../e2e"],
    "testMatch": [  
      "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" // default
    ]
}
```